# Read/Write Sequence Files Containing Thrift Records Using Hadoop Streaming with Python

Tags: python, hadoop, thrift

I would like to Read/Write sequence files containing Thrift records using Hadoop Streaming with Python. I have looked at the following and its seems this is possible after HADOOP-1722 but if someone has done this already and can give an example, that would be great.

http://mojodna.net/2013/12/27/binary-streaming-with-hadoop-and-nodejs.html

[How to use "typedbytes" or "rawbytes" in Hadoop Streaming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15171514/how-to-use-typedbytes-or-rawbytes-in-hadoop-streaming)

http://static.last.fm/johan/huguk-20090414/klaas-hadoop-1722.pdf

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-1722

The key is to be able to read thrift objects from stdin in Python.

Comment: I never thought about having [link-only](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=link+only+answer) questions. Obviously it is possible. Is it good? I would doubt that. Could you improve the question to fit [SO's quality standards](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites)?

Comment: Are there any specific clarifications/elaborations you think are needed on the question? Is the question not clear?

Comment: do you have the seq file containing the thrift record?

Comment: Yes, I have a sequence files containing thrift records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got this done with [Hadoopy](http://www.hadoopy.com/en/latest/).

This is my simple Thrift object.

```
struct Test {
    1: required string foo;
    2: required string bar;
}
```

I generated the python definitions using the command line tool, and zipped the directory. Then I generated some data and pushed it into HDFS using loadtb.

Here is the code to de-serialize the data and simply write it out as a string.

```
import hadoopy
from thrift.protocol import TBinaryProtocol
from thrift.TSerialization import deserialize
import sys

class Mapper(object):
    def __init__(self):
        sys.path.append('lib/test.zip/gen-py')
        from Test.ttypes import Test
        self.protocol_factory = TBinaryProtocol.TBinaryProtocolFactory
        self.test = Test()
    def map(self, key, value):
        deserialize(self.test, key, protocol_factory=self.protocol_factory())
        yield 1, self.test.foo + " "  + self.test.bar

if __name__ == '__main__':
    hadoopy.run(Mapper)
```

This is the driver script.

```
import hadoopy

    hadoopy.launch('/data/fuscala', '/data/fuscala-output', 'fuscala1.py', remove_output = True, files = ["test.zip"])
    data = hadoopy.readtb('/data/fuscala-output')
    for i, j in data:
        print i,j
```